# Analog front end for OECT sensor

Tags: circuit-design, analog

I've been asked to recreate/improve the circuit from [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2589004220311639#mmc1). Here is an extract that describes the function of it:

[image: Schematic]

> "Each circuit was composed of a voltage output (Vout GD or Vout SD)  connected to one end of a precision resistor (RG or RS). The other end of the resistor was connected to a voltage input ( Vin GD or Vin SD) and to the gate or source terminals. The drain terminal was connected to the ground of the microcontroller. Externally the gate, source and drain terminals were connected to the OECT using a ZIF connector and a ribbon cable (Figure 3B). Two proportional-integral-derivative (PID) controllers were used to control the voltages applied to the gate and source terminals of the OECT. Upon application of Vout, the voltage loss over R reduces the voltage at the gate/source terminal. The PID compensates for this by measuring Vin and modulating Vout so that Vin matches the desired gate/source voltage. The voltage over R, obtained from the difference between Voutand Vin, was used to calculate IG and IS through Ohm's law using the known value of R."

The circuit is simple enough but it strikes me as odd to use two PID loops to gain the IG and IS measurements. It seems like an op-amp base analog front end would do a much better job but I'm struggling to conceptualise how this would be designed. Any ideas?